# Magento promotions cart rules

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm looking for a solution to only give the products whom are in stock and have a qty more then 0 to have a discount regardless the total quantity the customer orders.

Example:

- product 1 (qty: 1)
- product 2 (qty: 0)
- product 3 (qty: 4)

products 1 and 3 will have a discount and product 2 does not.

At default this is not a function available in Magento 1 > cart price rules.

Also I cannot find a module which will give me these options.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
We've solved the issue by creating a category, not visible on frontend, that holds all the products with a qty above 0. Via a cronjob the products will either be removed or added to the category. By using the cart price rules we were able to set only the discounts on the regarding products.

Comment: It is hardly perfect, and you would have to set up an observer to keep it updated when a product's stock is depleted, but you could add an attribute like `stock_status` and set it to 'yes' for `Used for Promo Rule Conditions`.  The observer would be an entirely different animal...

Comment: This could be the solution to my problem indeed. Instead we've created a category that holds all the products with a qty above 0. Via a cronjob the products will either be removed or added to the category.